# Spresense ai人間を検出し　信号を出すだけのやり方

Tags: spresense, arduino

Spresenseにカメラを接続し
AIで人間を検知し信号出すだけのサンプルプログラムとかありますでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

SpresenseのSDKで、TensorflowLMのPaersonDetectのサンプルを動かすコンフィグがありますね。

./tools/config.py examples/tf_example_persondetect

でコンフィグしてビルド出来ます。